# React Async example with useState not working as expected, what is the problem?

Tags: reactjs, function, asynchronous, callback, state

React is super new to me and learning some async concepts. Currently, there is working code that I commented out. You can see that the working code takes in `useState(0)`. 0 as the value, while the none working useState takes in an object, `useState({ counter: 0})`. Why is it giving me an error and outputting [object Object]1 and NaN rather than number expected output of numbers?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Async = () => {
    const [currentState, setState] = useState({
        counter: 0
    });

// Can we have prevCounter as an argument? 
// *The two methods below are incorrect!*

const increase = () => {
    setTimeout(
        () => setState((prevCounter) => ({
            counter: prevCounter + 1
        })
        ), 500
    );
} // will output [object Object]1

const decrease = () => {
    setTimeout(
        () => setState((prevCounter) => ({
            counter: prevCounter - 1
        })
        ), 500
    )
} // will output NaN

// This portion works fine. Above does not.
/* const [currentState, setState] = useState(0);

const increase = () => {
    setTimeout(
        () => setState(prevCounter => prevCounter + 1)
        , 500
    );
}

const decrease = () => {
    setTimeout(
        () => setState(prevCounter => prevCounter - 1)
        , 500
    );
} */

return(
    <div>
        <h1>{currentState.counter}</h1>  
        {console.log(currentState.counter)}
        <button onClick={increase}>Increase</button>
        <button onClick={decrease}>Decrease</button>
    </div>  
  );
}

export default Async;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to correctly access the state object `counter` property `currentState.counter`, or in this case `prevCounter.counter` since that is what you named the previous state object in the functional state update.

`prevCounter` is an object so when you apply an arithmetic operation on it the result should be `NaN` as expected.

```
const increase = () => {
    setTimeout(
        () => setState((prevCounter) => ({
            counter: prevCounter.counter + 1
        })
        ), 500
    );
} // will output [object Object]1

const decrease = () => {
    setTimeout(
        () => setState((prevCounter) => ({
            counter: prevCounter.counter - 1
        })
        ), 500
    )
}
```

Comment: Drew, thank you. I was going crazy, I knew I was on the right path, I never knew that if you pass something in as an argument, it would be an Object as well.